# Lack of selecting capacity with if statement / append method

Tags: jquery-ui, autocomplete

I want to propose an autocomplete list (jquery ui 1.8) with some words in bold font.

The JSON source looks like :

```
{"especes":[{"fk_sp":number,"nom_espece":name,"nom_valide":0 or 1}].
```

My script is like that :

```
$(function(){
    $('#id').autocomplete({
    source: function(request, response) {
        $.getJSON("fichier.php", {
            term: request.term
        }, function(data) {                     
            var array = data.error ? [] : $.map(data.especes, function(m) {
                return {
                    label: m.nom_espece,
                    value: m.fk_sp,
                    valid: m.nom_valide
                };
            });
            response(array);
        });
    },
    select: function (event, ui) {
      $("#espece").val(ui.item.label);    
      $("#fk_sp").val(ui.item.value); 
    }
    }).data( "ui-autocomplete" )._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {
return $( "<li></li>" )
    .data( "item.autocomplete", item )
    .append( item.valid == '1' ? "<b>" + item.label + "</b>" : item.label)
    .appendTo( ul );
    };
});
```

If I use :

.data( "ui-autocomplete" ) => I have the good selectable list without the bold lines,

.data( "ui-Autocomplete" ) ou .data( "uiAutocomplete" ) => nothing works,

and if I juste write ._renderItem without .data( "ui-autocomplete" ) => I have a pretty list with the good names in bold, but I can't select any name of the list !

I don't find where is my error (I suppose it is somwhere with the "select :" part).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Unsure why you are adding those `data` elements. To render an item, you need to call the `instance` based on jQuery UI Examples. So asking for clarification.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! It seems to work with ` .autocomplete( "instance" )._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {
      return $( "<li>" )
      .append( item.valid == '1' ? "<div style='font-weight: bold;'>" + item.label + "</div>" : item.label)
        .appendTo( ul );` using jquery-ui 1.12.1